# Firebase Auth Persistance in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm using Firebase email + pw sign in for my React Native application, but the login doesn't seem to persist after the app is closed and reopened.  I read in the documentation that the default is to persist, so I'm not sure why it's not behaving that way?

I'm using the following on componentWillMount:

```
this.state.dbh.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            this.state = {
                user: user
            }
        }
```

I'm also using Expo to develop - would this have an effect on persisting the login?

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to `setPersistence` but Firebase SDK accepts only `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE` otherwise returns an error `{code: "auth/unsupported-persistence-type", message: "The current environment does not support the specified persistence type."}`.

Comment: The aforementioned applies for both Expo and vanilla react-native app. Thus Expo is unlikely the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regression introduced in Firebase v4.5.1 as described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/223).

Solution:

1. Downgrade to Firebase v4.5.0
2. Restart Expo with `npm start -- --reset-cache`

**Edit:**

The issue is fixed in [Firebase v4.5.2](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/releases/tag/firebase%404.5.2).

1. Upgrade to Firebase v4.5.2
2. Change Firebase import

   ```
   // from
   import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
   import 'firebase/auth';

   // to
   import firebase from 'firebase';
   ```

As described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/223#issuecomment-336601373).

Comment: Thanks!  I also wrapped my login/sign in methods with the following:

firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => { // Do login/sign in }